# Why are there two entries for Remote Desktop in my Windows Defender Firewall listing of allowed apps

Tags: remote-desktop, group-policy, windows-firewall

I have just started getting an "internal error" when trying to Remote Desktop connect from my PC to a server on the LAN.  It's been working fine for several years.

I cannot reach our external network support group to find out what is going on, so I'm trying to troubleshoot my own firewall settings.

Remote Desktop is listed twice. Why is that? Do I have the ability to override Group Policy settings? I do have some admin privileges.

[image: Windows Firewall allowed apps]

Comment: In order to override the group policy, you would have to be an admin on the active directory domain.  Being a local administrator will not be sufficient in a case like this.

Comment: I have this entry twice in my own system (one entry adds websocket). You need to contact your own company support and ask them to fix this or help you fix it.